# Entity Framework - "eager loading" using .Include() and .Select() - how to use a LEFT JOIN rather than INNER JOIN?

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, eager-loading

Here is a query I'm working on in Entity Framework 5.0.0 RC (code first) with .NET 4.0

I'm new to Entity Framework, so I'm still getting my head around how to structure the queries, particularly around selecting "child" related data.

I'm using "eager loading" so I get all of the related data at once. But I'm having a problem in that not all of the Drops are being retrieved.

```
var loads = context.Loads
            .Include(
                p => p.Device
            )
            .Include(
                p => p.Drops.Select(
                    a => a.Customer
                )
            ).Include(
                q => q.Drops.Select(
                   b => b.Items.Select(
                       c => c.Product
                   )
                )
            ).Where(
                u => u.Id.Equals(id)
            );
```

The problem is that in the generated SQL query, the Customers are being INNER JOINED to the Drops, thus excluding Drops which don't have a Customer.

So how do I make it do a LEFT JOIN between those two entities?

.Include appears to do left joins - so why not .Select ?

Is there a method other than .Select that I can use which will do a LEFT JOIN ?

---

**UPDATE**

After chatting with Amiram I realised that I had set my Drop model up incorrectly. I needed to set the CustomerID column to be optional:

```
public class Drop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int LoadId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DropItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I should have immediately thought of this, but to be honest I was put off by the fact that .Include() always does a LEFT JOIN, regardless of the cardinality in the relationship of the models. I was thinking .Select() must have some similar behaviour, but no it was just obeying how the model was configured :)

Comment: What happens if you write  p => p.Drops.Select(a => a.Customer).DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: @AmiramKorach - I get an error: *The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties
Parameter name: path*

Comment: Because your question is very interesting I tried it now with the same tables, and everything is fine. A drop is loaded even if it doesn't have a customer. I didn't use code first, but database first.

Comment: @AmiramKorach - So if you were to output the generated SQL query, are you saying it doesn't have an INNER JOIN ? That's weird.

Comment: I didn't check the sql query, only the results. I saw that I got also a drop without a customer.

Comment: @AmiramKorach I assume that it must not be doing the INNER JOIN for you then. I just don't know why it would generate different SQL for you compared to me. To confirm it, you can just create a variable like this `var sql = loads.ToString();` then set a breakpoint on it - that will show you the generated SQL.

Comment: SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project1].[LoadId] AS [LoadId], 
[Project1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID]
FROM ( SELECT 
 [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
 [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
 [Extent2].[LoadId] AS [LoadId], 
 [Extent2].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID], 
 CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
 FROM  [dbo].[Load] AS [Extent1]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Drop] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[LoadId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC

Comment: @AmiramKorach - Thanks mate. But I don't think yours has "eager loaded" anything from the Customer table. It has selected the CustomerId column (which comes from the Drop entity), but has not eager loaded customer data such as Customer.Name etc. To do that it needs to join on the Customer table - which is where I was getting that damn INNER JOIN coming from.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14458/discussion-between-amiram-korach-and-asgeo1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drops are inner joined with customers since Drop.CustomerID is of type int and not nullable int (Look in the chat).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to make my CustomerID column of type "int?"  :O   Thanks